# Как в кастомном эдиторе Unity вывести экземпляры подкласса, которые описаны в самом классе

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Есть класс, допустим `Res`, а в нем другой класс `SubRes`

```
public class Res : ScriptableObject
{
    [System.Serializable] public class SubRes
    {
        [SerializeField] protected float[] myFloatArray;
        [SerializeField] protected MyEnum[] myEmunArray;
    } 

    [SerializeField] protected SubRes mySubRes1;
    [SerializeField] protected SubRes mySubRes2;
}
```

Для `Res` сделан кастомный эдитор который выводит другие его поля, но как мне вывести с помощью кастомного эдитора экземпляры подклассов так как мне нужно? как их вообще выводить?

Comment: Точно так-же...

Comment: Ну получить SerializedProperty экземпляра подкласса и вывести его через EditorGUILayout.PropertyField я то могу, а как выводить отдельно массивы находящиеся внутри подклассов и манипулировать ими?

Comment: Найти по имени SerializedProperty в SerializedProperty как бы тупо это не звучало... А как еще ты себе это представляешь, если ты знаешь что это поле в этом поле?

Comment: У SerializedProperty'сов нет FindProperty, только FindProperyRelative... Нужно использовать его? Я думал это что то для получения полей из общего класса в котором экземпляр самого подкласса...)

Comment: Да,у меня все получилось) Спасибо

Comment: `SerializedObject.FindProperty` - найти сериализуемое поле в сер. объекте. `SerializedProperty.FindPropertyRelative` - найти сер. поле относящееся к сер. полю. `Relative` - перевод: "относительно". Названия методов в контексте их классов буквально говорящие, как это и должно быть у хороших программистов! Вся проблема в собственных ожиданиях и половой драмы с английским) И тут не нужно обладать уровнем англ. **C2**, я с своим ничтожным **A2**-**B1** это читаю.